# Using re.findall() to search text for multiple criteria [python3.8]

Tags: python, regex, python-re

***edited to divert attention from the type of text data I'm using and redirect attention to the actual question***

***Further edited to note that:***

1. The linked question on the closing notice does not in any way help me with my issue, and in fact went as far as to further confuse me with an abundance of criteria and syntax
2. I have found a solution to the problem herein and will share it as an answer upon this question reopening so that anyone else with this same issue will have at least a starting point, if not a resolution to this issue.

**Situation:**

I have written a program that uses the requests module to grab all the ***text*** from a website, given that I use the exact same code for a system that does work, this piece is not an issue.
I am trying to use `re.findall()` to grab data in the order it appears. In the system that works, the line I use is

```
paragraphs = re.findall(r'c1(.*?)c1', str(mytext))
```

***where c1 stands in place of my first set of criteria*** I then use a few lines to get rid of what I don't need.

**What I've tried:**

I've attempted the following pieces of code, and none have worked. The information I've been able to find sadly doesn't address my issue. We could theorise all day as to why a guide for this is scarce, but the fact is a few hours of google got me nowhere.

*First attempt:*

I tried simply keeping it in-line

```
re.findall(r'c1(.*?)c1c2(.*?)c2', str(mytext))
```

***where c2 stands in place of my second criteria*** Unfortunately this returns `[]` which is useless for me.

*Second attempt:*

I thought that maybe the way I did this was wrong, so I shuffled it around a bit

```
re.findall(r'c1(.*?)c1', r'c2(.*?)c2', str(mytext))

re.findall(r'c1(.*?)c1'r'c2(.*?)c2', str(mytext))

re.findall(r'c1(.*?)c1' or 'c2(.*?)c2', str(mytext))

re.findall(r'c1(.*?)c1' or r'c2(.*?)c2', str(mytext))
```

But in the case of the first two, same as my initial attempt. The last two got only `c1(.*?)c1`, which is useful data, but it doesn't contain the `c2(.*?)c2` at all, let alone in the order it appears in the ***text***.

*Third attempt:*

**Don't run this code** this crashed my laptop with an infinite loop. I had done some research by this point and discovered the `re.search()` function

```
paragraphs = []
ticker = ''
while ticker != 'None':
    ticker = re.search(r'c1(.*?)c1', str(mytext))
    if (ticker == 'None'):
        ticker = re.search(r'c2(.*?)c2', str(mytext))
    if (ticker != 'None'):
        paragraphs.append(ticker)
print(paragraphs)
```

Clearly, this was a dumb idea. It tried to make the `paragraphs[]` have an infinite list of the first `c1(.*?)c1`.

**Question:**

How, if at all, do I use `re.findall()` to create a list `paragraphs` that will go through the ***text*** in `mytext` and pick out everything that meets the criteria `c1(.*?)c1` and `c2(.*?)c2` and place them in the order they appear?

eg
if the ***text*** is (spaces added for clarity, will not exist in file)

```
c2 hello c2 c1 world c1 c2 !!! c2
```

The program will be

```
#get the text
#do the re.findall() function and assign to the list paragraphs
print(paragraphs)
```

And will return

```
>>>['hello', 'world', '!!!']
```

Comment: may I ask, why you're not using an HTML parser like beautifulsoup? [regex is not meant to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: This is the kind of problem I'm always tempted to work on, but I know I'll get downvoted if I actually offer an RE-based answer. I like REs too, but I have to agree with the previous comment, it's better to use an HTML parser... It'll save you a lot of gotchas in the long run.

Comment: @Chase I much prefer regex to beautifulsoup even though I'm more familiar with bs4 than regex. I'm making sure to copy the content of the HTML to a python variable so that I'm not directly parsing the HTML file itself.

Comment: @joanis if you know a solution in regex I would much appreciate it, even if we have to go off-site to avoid downvotes

Comment: Looks like you need `[x.group() for x in re.finditer(r'(c1|c2)(.*?)\1', mytext)]` or `[x.group() for x in re.finditer(r'(c1|c2)((?:(?!c1|c2).)*?)\1', mytext, flags=re.S)]`

Comment: also just to allude to the snippet that "crashes computers". You're comparing `ticker` to `'None'`. In python, `None` does not equal `'None'` - one is a string literal and the other....well it's a keyword for `NoneType`. So that loop is literally infinite and it is so for a rather obvious reason.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew fine answer! Remember to do `.group(2)` to achieve OP's desired output. Note should be taken when using `re.S` though, `DOTALL` is dangerous....and also one of the reasons html shouldn't be parsed with regex. I hope OP's texts within `c1/c2` tags don't contain newlines so they don't have to use `DOTALL`

Comment: @WCJ277 Good idea to rewrite the question like you did, now at least people are really reading your question. I think the solution by Wiktor will work for you. The magic you need is there: `(c1|c2)` to match either criterion, and then `\1` to match it again where each instance ends. If the opening `c2` and closing `c2` are not actually verbatim equal in your real problem, you might need something a bit fancier, but the base logic should still work.

Comment: Check [Python demo](https://ideone.com/M8zF2D) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RWs2GW/1).

Comment: @chase oh no I'm not comparing to the python None, theres actual strings which fit my criteria that read "None". I should've clarified that in the post, my bad

Comment: @joanis it would be great if moderators didn't close it. The linked question definitely isn't the same as mine, and the answers only serve to make me more confused about regex as its full of syntax that I guess most people have committed to memory.

Comment: Just voted to reopen, because I think it's an interesting and worthwhile question, sufficiently different from the duplicate link. Do Wiktor's Python and regex demos in his last comment above solve your problem?

Comment: This was not closed by a moderator. The dupicate shows exactly how to use a single regex to check a string for multiple conditions; if that's what you want, you need lookaheads. Of course, you can always `if re.search(r'c1', str) and re.search(r'c2', str):` but that doesn't seem to be what you are asking.

Comment: Please provide feedback on the solution posted.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
[x.group(2) for x in re.finditer(r'(c1|c2)(.*?)\1', mytext, flags=re.S)]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RWs2GW/1). Or, to match the shortest substrings:

```
[x.group(2) for x in re.finditer(r'(c1|c2)((?:(?!c1|c2).)*?)\1', mytext, flags=re.S)]
```

The regex matches

- `(c1|c2)` - Group 1: `c1` or `c2`
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0 or more chars as few as possible
- `\1` - the same value as in Group 1.

The `for x in re.finditer(r'(c1|c2)(.*?)\1', mytext)` iterates over all matches and `x.group(2)` will return Group 2 values only.

Answer (score -1):

Try to put "OR" in between for multiple conditions:

```py
re.findall(r'c1(.*?)c2', mytext) or re.findall(r'c2(.*?)c3', mytext)
```